# C# ComboBox in DataGridView is not clickable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, combobox

I've added a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to my DataGrid, it shows up but I cannot open the dropdown by clicking on it.
When hovering with the mouse, the box is highlighted.

I have this code for adding it:

```
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colCombo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    colCombo.HeaderText = "State";
    colCombo.Name = "combo";
    colCombo.Items.Add("Open");
    colCombo.Items.Add("Close");
    dataGridView_targets.Columns.Add(colCombo);
```

This is what I see, clicking on the ComboBox doesn't work.
[image]

Comment: worked for me just fine... took 2 clicks, but works. that's just how the combobox works

Comment: I tried two (and more..) clicks, nothing.

Comment: does the rest of the DataGridView is enabled and working properly?

Comment: The only reason your combobox doesn't pop up is **there are not any items in it**

Comment: Do you have a PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event on this DataGrid? I think that's the problem with my DataGrid (in WPF though) but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 4):

This situation can be, if the property "ReadOnly" has value True for your DataGridView

Comment: Nope. My DataGrid is set to ReadOnly=False;

Answer (score 0):

I followed your code snippet and everything worked as expected.  My workflow was I created a winform app, added a datagridview to it and then took your code snippet and shoved it into the constructor.  Are there any other pieces you have that might be influencing this result?  Any other code you can post that may help the community answer better?

I did see that if the `datagridview_targets.AllowUserToAddRows = false` , this can stop the combo box from being able to be used as intended.  For some reason I cannot see the image you posted, so not sure what the exact result is that you are seeing.